# How can I parse column of .csv file instead of writing the values manually

Tags: html, id3

I want to be able to represent a bar chart by using only two columns in my .csv file, I have written a temporary solution by writing manually the values of the columns.. But if I have more columns, or more values in every column it may become impossible to write it manually. I'd love to get some help on how to transform my code to read the columns from the .csv file, so far I've been able to get a single bar chart and wasn't able to further edit the code for using more columns to get a multiple bar chart. Also, after finding the code for multiple bar charts - it traversed on all the columns on the .csv file and it showed all the columns in the chart, then when I tried editing the for loop for just the first two columns, and it didn't work, so I decided to write it manually for now.

**Question:** How to read .csv columns for bar chart representation (just two columns) instead of writing the column's values manually as I did.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{              
        title:{
            text: ""
        },
         axisX:{
       title: "car type"},
        axisY:{
        title:"$", 

         interval: 5000,
  },

    data: [
    {
        type: "column",
        yValueFormatString: "#.####",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "DealerCost",

        dataPoints: [
            { "label": "Regular", y: 27446.14286 },
            { "label": "Sports.car", y: 48473.16327 },
            { "label": "SUV", y: 31625.35},
            { "label": "Wagon", y: 26645.63333 },
            { "label": "Minivan", y: 25355.5 },
            { "label": "Pickup", y: 22616.75},
        ]
    },

    {
        type: "column",
        showInLegend: true,                  
        name: "RetailPrice",
        yValueFormatString: "#.####",
        dataPoints: [
            { "label": "Regular", y: 29814.3591836735 },
            { "label": "Sports.car", y: 53387.06122 },
            { "label": "SUV", y: 34790.25},
            { "label": "Wagon", y: 28840.53333 },
            { "label": "Minivan", y: 27796.5 },
            { "label": "Pickup", y: 24941.375},

        ]
    },

    ]
    });

    chart.render();
}
</script>

 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 50%;">
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly? I assume you are not a SO beginner.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Yeah you're correct. I've edited the code. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Is the .csv file read into a JavaScript string? If yes please provide an example string.

Comment: @5aledmaged I've uploaded a picture of the .csv file